# Populating Primary/foreign keys between multiple tables in SQL/Vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql

im creating a program in which users can upload songs, and those songs meta data such as its album or artist is recorded in a relational sql database. My current table setup consists of 3 tables- Song_DB, Album_DB, Artist_DB.

**SONG_DB:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SONGS_DB] (
[SONG_ID]          INT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[SONG_NAME]        NCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[ARTIST_ID]        INT         NULL,
[ALBUM_ID]         INT         NULL,
[SONG_LENGTH]      TIME (0)    NOT NULL,
[SONG_PLAYLIST_ID] INT         NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SONG_ID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_SONGS_DB_ToARTIST] FOREIGN KEY ([ARTIST_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ARTIST_DB] ([ARTIST_ID]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_SONGS_DB_ToALBUM] FOREIGN KEY ([ALBUM_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ALBUM_DB] ([ALBUM_ID]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_SONGS_DB_ToSONG_PLAYLIST] FOREIGN KEY ([SONG_PLAYLIST_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[SONG_PLAYLIST] ([SONG_PLAYLIST_ID])
```

**Artist_DB**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ARTIST_DB] (
    [ARTIST_ID] INT  IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [SONG_ID]   INT  NULL,
    [NAME]      TEXT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ARTIST_ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ARTIST_DB_ToSONGS_DB] FOREIGN KEY ([SONG_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[SONGS_DB] ([SONG_ID])
);
```

**Album_DB**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ALBUM_DB] (
[ALBUM_ID] INT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[SONG_ID]  INT         NULL,
[NAME]     NCHAR (100) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ALBUM_ID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_ALBUM_DB_SONGS] FOREIGN KEY ([SONG_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[SONGS_DB] ([SONG_ID])
```

);

Im trying to write to the tables once a song is uploaded and the meta data is collected into variables. THe actual writing i have down but im struggling to figure out how to populate the foreign key tables. For example with the following code, neither song_ID populates in Artist/album_DB nor does Album/artist_ID in Song_DB-

```
   Dim SQLcon As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\coolj\OneDrive\Documents\Loop\Loop\Songs_SQL.mdf;Integrated Security=True"}

                Dim SQLCmd As SqlCommand
                Dim SQLCmd2 As SqlCommand
                Dim SQLCmd3 As SqlCommand
                Dim SQLCmd4 As SqlCommand
                Dim SQLCmd5 As SqlCommand
                Dim SQLCmd_SID As SqlCommand
                Dim SQLCmd_ARID As SqlCommand
                Dim SQLCmd_ALID As SqlCommand
                Dim SQLCmd_ARID2 As SqlCommand
                Dim SQLCmd_ALID2 As SqlCommand
                Dim SID
                Dim ARID
                Dim ALID
                SQLcon.Open()
                SQLCmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SONGS_DB (SONG_NAME, SONG_LENGTH) VALUES (@SONG_NAME, @SONG_LENGTH)", SQLcon)
                SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SONG_NAME", Title)
                SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SONG_LENGTH", Duration)
                SQLCmd_SID = New SqlCommand("SELECT max(SONG_ID) FROM SONGS_DB", SQLcon)


                If SID = "" Then
                    SID += 1

                Else
                    SID = SQLCmd_SID.ExecuteScalar()
                    SID = Convert.ToInt32(SID)
                End If



                If Album IsNot "" Then
                    SQLCmd2 = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ALBUM_DB (NAME) VALUES (@NAME)", SQLcon)
                    SQLCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", Album)
                    'SQLCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SONG_ID", SID)
                End If

                If Artist IsNot "" Then
                    SQLCmd3 = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ARTIST_DB (NAME) VALUES (@NAME)", SQLcon)
                    SQLCmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", Artist)
                    'SQLCmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SONG_ID", SID)

                End If



                SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                If Album IsNot "" Then
                    SQLCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End If
                If Artist IsNot "" Then
                    SQLCmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End If

                If Artist IsNot "" Then
                    SQLCmd_ARID = New SqlCommand("SELECT max(ARTIST_ID) FROM ARTIST_DB", SQLcon)
                    If ARID = "" Then
                        ARID += 1

                    Else
                        ARID = SQLCmd_ARID.ExecuteScalar()
                        ARID = Convert.ToInt32(ARID)
                    End If
                    SQLCmd_ARID2 = New SqlCommand("UPDATE SONG_DB SET ARTIST_ID = (@ARTIST_ID) WHERE SONG_ID = (@SONG_ID)", SQLcon)
                    SQLCmd_ARID2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ARTIST_ID", ARID)
                    SQLCmd_ARID2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SONG_ID", SID)


                End If

                If Album IsNot "" Then
                    SQLCmd_ALID = New SqlCommand("SELECT max(ALBUM_ID) FROM ALBUM_DB", SQLcon)
                    If ALID = "" Then
                        ALID += 1

                    Else
                        ALID = SQLCmd_ARID.ExecuteScalar()
                        ALID = Convert.ToInt32(ARID)
                    End If
                    SQLCmd_ALID2 = New SqlCommand("UPDATE SONG_DB SET ARTIST_ID = (@ARTIST_ID) WHERE SONG_ID = (@SONG_ID)", SQLcon)
                    SQLCmd_ALID2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ARTIST_ID", ARID)
                    SQLCmd_ALID2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SONG_ID", SID)


                End If

                If Artist IsNot "" Then
                    SQLCmd_ARID2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End If

                If Album IsNot "" Then
                    SQLCmd_ALID2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End If
                SQLcon.Close()
            End If
```

Any ideas where im going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your database design is flawed. The `SONG_ID` column does not belong in `Artist_DB` or in `Album_DB`. In fact, in the real world, the same song might be performed by multiple artists and appear in multiple albums, while each artists may perform multiple songs and produce multiple albums. I would suggest an artists table, an album table, a songs table, a many-to-many bridge table between artists and albums, and a many-to-many bridge table between this new table and the songs table.

Comment: (continue)  This would enable you to describe actual, real world situations where the same song appears in two albums by two different artists, or two artists creating an album together.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. 
You can find this setting in 
Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults.
This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: `If SID = "" Then
                    SID += 1` What is SID? A string? A number? Option Strict would force you to declare this as a type.

Comment: `If Album IsNot "" Then` Validation should have been performed long before this.

Answer (score 1):

```
            If Album IsNot "" Then
                SQLCmd2 = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ALBUM_DB (NAME) VALUES (@NAME)", SQLcon)
                SQLCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", Album)
                'SQLCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SONG_ID", SID)
            End If

            If Artist IsNot "" Then
                SQLCmd3 = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ARTIST_DB (NAME) VALUES (@NAME)", SQLcon)
                SQLCmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", Artist)
                'SQLCmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SONG_ID", SID)

            End If
```

You have half of this code within quotation marks.
Replace with:

```
        If Album IsNot "" Then
            SQLCmd2 = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ALBUM_DB (NAME) VALUES (@NAME)", SQLcon)
            SQLCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", Album)
            SQLCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SONG_ID", SID)
        End If

        If Artist IsNot "" Then
            SQLCmd3 = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ARTIST_DB (NAME) VALUES (@NAME)", SQLcon)
            SQLCmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", Artist)
            SQLCmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SONG_ID", SID)

        End If
```

As stated in the comments, the lines below are not adding anything to the insert statement because there is no `@SONG_ID` parameter within the statement. This could also be causing issues.

`SQLCmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SONG_ID", SID)
 SQLCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SONG_ID", SID)`

Comment: But you are adding parameters that are not part of the Insert statement.